# How to determine two different aggregate dates on employee attendance data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Need help to implement employee attendance sheet. Presently am having employee attendance i.e

Query:

```
SELECT c.First_name + c.Middle_name + c.last_name AS employeename,
       b.Device_Person_id,a.Dept_Id,Date1, 
       CASE WHEN b.Device_Person_id IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 'P' 
            ELSE 'A' END AS status
FROM Emp_setting a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Device_Person_id, MAX(logDateTime) AS Date1 
                 FROM tempDeviceLogs 
                 GROUP BY Device_Person_id) b
    ON a.personal_id = b.Device_Person_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN persons_profile c 
    ON c.pesonal_id=a.personal_id
```

Result:

```
employeename      Device_person_id      dept_id      date1                status

MEHABOOB             NULL                 4         NULL                    A
UDAY                 NULL                 26    NULL                        A  
SHANKRAYYA           NULL                 10    NULL                        A
BASAVARAJ            NULL                 24    NULL                        A
BHIMAPPA              5                   10       2014-05-23 14:14:00.000      P
```

i.e. Employeename `BHIMAPPA` is present on `2014-05-23`.

NOW I want the list of employees who is present on 2014-05-23.

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `logDateTime` indicates the presence of the employee, and given that the current derived table returns the `MAX()` of this field (presumably the last time the employee was detected) you would need another join to the `tempDeviceLogs` table to do the filtering. You could do the filtering at the same time with an `INNER JOIN`, viz:

```
...
INNER JOIN (SELECT Device_Person_id 
            FROM tempDeviceLogs 
            WHERE logDateTime >= '2014-05-23' and logDateTime < '2014-05-24') x
   ON x.Device_Person_id = a.personal_id
```

**Edit**
Given that you want to `SELECT` the date as well, I'm assuming you want to parameterize it / use it for a range. And making yet another assumption about your SqlServer version being >= 2008, cast the `DateTime` to a `Date` and group by it:

```
SELECT c.First_name + c.Middle_name + c.last_name AS employeename,
      b.Device_Person_id,a.Dept_Id, Date1 as DateTimeLastSeen, 
      x.logDate As DatePresent,
      CASE WHEN b.Device_Person_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'P' ELSE 'A' END AS status
FROM Emp_setting a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Device_Person_id, MAX(logDateTime) AS Date1 
                   FROM tempDeviceLogs 
                   GROUP BY Device_Person_id) b 
     ON a.personal_id = b.Device_Person_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN persons_profile c 
     ON c.pesonal_id=a.personal_id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Device_Person_id, CAST(logDateTime AS DATE) as logDate
              FROM tempDeviceLogs 
              GROUP BY Device_Person_id, CAST(logDateTime AS DATE)) x
  ON x.Device_Person_id = a.personal_id
WHERE 
     logDate BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-23';
```

This could also be done with a DISTINCT. If you have an earlier version of SqlServer, use a [hack like this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/122-getting-only-the-date-part-of-a-date-time-stamp-in-sql-server.htm) to obtain the date part of a `DateTime` (in the select + group)

Comment: Thank you so much it's working is it possible to show date column also?

Comment: sorry but where to declare it. don't have idea

Comment: it causing error  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
Incorrect syntax near 'b'.
Incorrect syntax near 'x'.

Comment: There was a comma missing, viz: `x.logDate As DatePresent,`. Also, check your SqlServer version is >= 2008.

Comment: Once again Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to hold the date which you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @cutOffDate DATE
SET @cutOffDate = '23-05-2014'
```

Then add to the end of your statement

```
Where Date1 = @cutOffDate
```